# PERROR torsocks [2893]

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, error, torsocks

I am trying to get Tor relay working and I obviously have done some thing wrong, as I keep getting the torsocks PERROR when testing.

I entered the command `curl https://api.ipify.org` and get `82.3.5.110` as reply. I then try `torsocks curl https://api.ipify.org` and always get the error:

```
steve@TorServer:torsocks curl https://api.ipify.org
[Apr 25 11:41:33] PERROR torsocks[2893]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:185)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.ipify.org
```

The debug output is:

```
steve@TorServer:/etc/tor$ torsocks -d curl https://api.ipify.org
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Logging subsytem initialized. Level 5, file (null), time 1 (in init_logging() at torsocks.c:286)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Config file not provided by TORSOCKS_CONF_FILE. Using default /etc/tor/torsocks.conf (in config_file_read() at config-file.c:531)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Config file setting tor address to 127.0.0.1 (in set_tor_address() at config-file.c:179)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Config file setting tor port to 9050 (in set_tor_port() at config-file.c:142)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [config] Onion address range set to 127.42.42.0/24 (in set_onion_info() at config-file.c:108)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Config file /etc/tor/torsocks.conf opened and parsed. (in config_file_read() at config-file.c:560)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [fclose] Close catched for fd 4 (in tsocks_fclose() at fclose.c:45)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [onion] Pool init with subnet 127.42.42.0 and mask 24 (in onion_pool_init() at onion.c:104)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [onion] Pool initialized with base 0, max_pos 255 and size 8 (in onion_pool_init() at onion.c:132)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Close catched for fd 4 (in tsocks_close() at close.c:33)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Close catched for fd 5 (in tsocks_close() at close.c:33)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [socket] Creating socket with domain 10, type 2 and protocol 0 (in tsocks_socket() at socket.c:33)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: IPv4/v6 non TCP socket denied. Tor network can't handle it. (in tsocks_socket() at socket.c:59)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [getaddrinfo] Requesting api.ipify.org hostname (in tsocks_getaddrinfo() at getaddrinfo.c:44)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Resolving api.ipify.org on the Tor network (in tsocks_tor_resolve() at torsocks.c:527)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: Setting up a connection to the Tor network on fd 4 (in setup_tor_connection() at torsocks.c:350)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] PERROR torsocks[3814]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:185)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.ipify.org
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [onion] Destroying onion pool containing 0 entry (in onion_pool_destroy() at onion.c:148)
[Apr 25 14:36:17] DEBUG torsocks[3814]: [fclose] Close catched for fd 2 (in tsocks_fclose() at fclose.c:45)
```

Anyone can tell why the error appears and how to handle it?

The torrc I tried to add it to the question and I was told I cant as I dont have 2 points to my name?

torsocks.conf

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9050
OnionAddrRange 127.42.42.0/24
```

I have tried adding the torrc file but get an error message
"You neeed at least 10 reputations to post more than 2 links"

So how do I get help if I cant post it? - and I do need help here

Comment: Edit your question to include the output. Also please provider your `torrc` file contents in your question.

Comment: I use Tor Browser

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Tor Browser's Tor instance you'll have to use `TorPort 9150`. Alternatively, you can install a global Tor instance.

This doesn't work if you're running the alpha version of Tor Broswer on a Unix-like system, it uses a [Unix socket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/14270) instead. You should also expect the stable series to switch to Unix sockets before long.

Comment: ok i'm away for 2 days a will try and sort out what you need me to do . thanks

Comment: @Ysblik Please don't edit the answers to add questions. To answer your question, open the config menu →click the '?' → About Tor Browser, if you see "You are currently on the **alpha** update channel" then your using alpha. Also, unless you picked a browser from the "[Experimental Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads-alpha)" section on the download page your not running alpha.